# Creating a Correlation matrix with existing data in R

Tags: r, excel, matrix, correlation

So far, I have an Excel file with four columns. The first two columns contain all the variables that I have correlated with each other. The third column contains the correlation coefficients, and the fourth column contains the corresponding p-values.
Name of the 4 columns:
Variable 1
Variable 2
Korrelationskoeffizient
p-Wert

I now want to create a correlation matrix from this data to visualize it using R. The correlation coefficients should be displayed in the cells, and the corresponding p-values should be colour-coded. For example the bluer it is, the more significant it is, with a significance level of p<0.05.

Currently, I have only been able to import the data into R because I do not know how to create a correlation matrix with existing data. I do not need to calculate correlation coefficients as they are already available. Can someone help me with the code?

```
library("readxl")
data_inter <- read_excel("all.xlsx", na="NA")
```

Comment: Hi tom, welcome to SO. In order to make it easier to answer your question, please run `dput(data_inter)` or `dput(head(data_inter, 20))` if your dataset is large and copy the result into your question. Also, SO is focused on helping to debug coding and programming issues, it is not a code-writing service. In order to improve your question, please add what you have tried so far (even if it doesn't work). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you have only two variables? If so, why do you need the correlation matrix?

However, you can use the codes below to create and visualize the correlation matrix.

```
# install and run the package
install.packages("corrplot")
library(corrplot)

# data
data("mtcars")
data_1 <- mtcars[, 1:7]

# correlation matrix
correlation <- cor(data_1)
corrplot(correlation)
```